# Interchanging order of summation mechanically

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

How can I interchange order of summation mechanically, without thinking? For instance, I had to interchange the sums below (assume $i$ is a constant where $i\gt 0$).

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{i\lt k \lt n} a_{nk}$$

I wrote down a matrix, and read it by columns instead of rows, arrived at:

$$\sum_{k\gt i}\sum_{n\gt k} a_{nk}$$

Which I think it's correct.

But there must be a way to do it mechanically, without writing down the matrix. By mechanically, I mean something like what happens with this sum, where I can make the steps without thinking:

$$\sum_{n\gt k}\frac{1}{n} z^n = \sum_{n-k\gt k-k}\frac{1}{n} z^n $$
$$m=n-k\implies n=m+k$$
$$\sum_{n-k\gt 0}\frac{1}{n} z^n = \sum_{m\gt 0}\frac{1}{m+k} z^{m+k}$$

No thinking required here, just algebra.

Concrete Mathematics calls my example a "rocky road" double summation and suggests to use Iverson notation, but I haven't been able to apply it to my case.

Comment: The $i$ in your first and second formula does not make sense to me. Is this a constant?

Comment: Unless $i\ge-1$, your stated equality does not hold.

Comment: "No thinking required here, just algebra" is not true. Actually your result is ok. But if you dont know if the rules that you apply are allowed, you dont know if the result is true. Simply doing some algebra on parts of yor graphic (your summation formula) does not guarantee a correct result

Comment: $i$ is a given constant where $i\gt 0$, I'll add that.

Comment: If it's a sum over a subset of $\mathbb Z^2$ then I usually just draw a picture to make sure I'm summing over the same points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this way:

$$\begin{align*}\\\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=i + 1}^{n - 1} a_{n, k} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n, k} \cdot 1(i < k < n)\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n, k} \cdot 1(i < k < n)\\&= \sum_{k=i + 1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n, k} \cdot 1(k < n)\\&= \sum_{k=i + 1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} a_{n, k}\end{align*}$$

Comment: you are interchanging two  lim operation. Can you tell me why this is allowed here?

Comment: If series are absolutely convergent

Comment: Your solution was very clear to me, thanks!

Comment: @Ricbit I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that the constant $ i$ is at least $-1$, we have
$$ n\ge 1\;\land \;i<k<n\iff k>i\;\land\;n>k$$
Therefore (provided rearranging is justified because either we have absolute convergence or because instead of a series running to $\infty$ we really have a sun runnin to some $N$, say)
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=i+1}^{n-1}=\sum_{k=i+1}^\infty\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

I preassume that $i$ is some fixed nonnegative integer.

Let $b_{nk}=1$ if $n\geq1\wedge i<k<n$ and $b_{nk}=0$ otherwise.

Then: $$\sum_{n\geq1}\sum_{i<k<n}a_{nk}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{nk}b_{nk}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{nk}b_{nk}=\sum_{k>i}\sum_{n>k}a_{nk}$$

This of course if the sum is well-defined. No matrix needed.